# Get all the albums from facebook using nodejs and express

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api, express

I need to get all the albums from facebook using nodejs and express.I am using passport to authenticate the user.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy( {
clientID : FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
clientSecret : FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
callbackURL : FACEBOOK_CALL_BACK_URL,
profile : true
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
FB_ACCESS_TOKEN = accessToken;
process.nextTick(function() {
    console.log("FB_ACCESS_TOKEN : " + FB_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    return done(null, profile);
});
}));
```

In callback i am requesting for scope user_status,user_photos and offline_access

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'), {
scope : [ 'user_status', 'user_photos','offline_access']
}, function(req, res) {
});
```

To get all albums I am using

```
app.get('/albums', function(req, res) {
FB.setAccessToken(FB_ACCESS_TOKEN);
console.log("FB_ACCESS_TOKEN @@ : " + FB.getAccessToken());
FB.api('/me/albums', function(resp) {
    console.log("Albums " + JSON.stringify(resp));
});
});
```

But in console i am getting

> Albums {"data":[]}

Any help??

Comment: NOTE : I checked the fb javascript example http://www.fbrell.com/fb.api/photo-albums
In that the scope specified are "user_photos,friends_photos,user_photo_video_tags,friends_photo_video_tags".I just want the photos and so i used user_photos.

Comment: I am using facebook-node-sdk https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-node-sdk